# How data and data's address stored in RAM

Tags: assembly, ram

My question is where the address and actual data stored in RAM. Lets say we have 32 bit memory for each address so if our microprocessor address the ram and store that address in ram so where it stores actual data because there is no space to store data after addressing ram with 32 bit of address.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not every 'variable' needs own space.  In C a char *buf needs 4 bytes to store the pointer, a char field[] needs no extra space. field is a label used by the compiler. The compiler adresses the memory but doesn't store the adress.

In very early asm-days there was a directive  ORG. ORG 100h was used to switch the segment start to 100h. The assembler 'knows' the shift, but its not saved.

Comment: The processor doesn't store the address of the memory. It addresses the memory directly... The data resides in that memory that is addressed.

Comment: if address is not stored next time when we refer that address how microprocessor knows that where that variable is ?

Comment: Yasin - What OS to use (e.g. Linux? OSX? Windows?) and what programming language are you familiar with for reference?

Comment: Frank C- I am using Windows 7. I am familiar to java, C and Assembly

Comment: Take a read through this:  http://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/aviv/classes/ic221/s14/lec/06/lec.html#sec-1

Comment: Thank you very much -Frank C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addresses to memory are no different than addresses to your house.  there is some amount of information (street, city, state, zip, country, etc) that uniquely identifies your house.  and you and many other folks know you live there.  Likewise they have a place to live and an address.

the address goes into the memory on the address bus, and causes the logic to point at a specific location in that memory that is uniquely identified by that address, and then you can read and write that memory location.

so as you say lets say each memory location is 32 bits.  we still use byte based addressing so what if you were to address the 32 bit item at address 0x1234 the address bus (assume this is all physical and get those notions out of this simplistic discussion) has 0x1234>>2 or 0x48D on it.  and you can read or write that 32 bit location.  now if you wanted to access the BYTE at address 0x1235 lets say for example then for a read you would read the 32 bit word at address 0x48D and then isolate the one byte of interest (which one depends on your endianess, next to the bottom or next to the top).  If you wanted to write the byte at 0x1235 then you would need to READ 0x48D, modify the byte in question (next to top or next to bottom depending on endianness) and write it back.  Now that ram may have a layer that lets you use a mask or some other such mechanism so you dont see the read-modify-write, but it is there unless the ram is actually controlled at the byte level.

now just like when your friend comes to your house for a second time, they remember the address where you live, in the case of a house the address is printed on the house, in a memory the address is printed in so many words, basically it is in the wiring, but you dont store an address with the data at that address, you just use the address to get to the box and you look inside just like the address on the house is the wiring and you are the thing inside.

when a compiler writes a program or a programmer writes assembly or machine code, they keep notes of what variables (high level language concept) are kept where.  someone directly or indirectly (you indirectly by declaring a variable in your language of choice, the compiler almost directly by noting how many things it needs to store and their offset, the linker by applying the offset to .data or .bss, and then the virtual memmory/mmu that converts that to physical, and the operating system that decides what virtual maps to what physical and so on).  So the compiler basically specifies where in memory relative to your programs allocated ram, each item is, and that address is basically hardcoded into to he instructions of the program either as a pc relative offset or as a complete address.  then when executed an address is produced and the size of the transaction is also known from the instruction, it goes on the generic processor bus, then the memory controller (again simplistic here there is a lot of logic between the processor and the memory, some of it software managed) then knows the architecture of the memory how wide and how to perform the various sized transactions, and those transactions happen for you.

take some paper cups or plates and some pieces of information, paper with things on it.  number the plates or cups sequentially from 0 to in.  put one item of information in/on each.. you are now not only the processor but the bus and the memory controller and the program you know what location has what information and you are wired to know how to go back to that address and find that information.  it is no more complicated than that, just a bunch of wires and ones and zeros...

Comment: Thank you very much dwelch. So what i understood from here the RAM addresses already wired to microprocessor when we input the address it goes thru that specific wire to link with value in address. I mean when we talk to 32 bit ram inside of the ram every 32 bits wired to bus and thru that bus it goes to microprocessor. Is that correct ?

Comment: yes, there is no reason to assume that because you have a 32 bit address bus or 32 bit registers that the memory width is 32, bit they are two separate designs.  But once wired up properly that is how it works, just like when you write a letter and give it to the postal person, they deliver it to the right place.  the processor sends out a request and the logic in between takes it to the right place.

Comment: the memory will be designed and organized for a certain width and depth there will be a common bus used for data, sometimes a write data and read data sometimes reads and writes on the same wires that can go in and out.  But for a 32 bit wide memory, when an address is placed on the bus and say a read is selected then the logic makes the data wires match the values in the 32 bits that are "At that address".  select a different address and select read and a different 32 bits values are sent on those same data wires.

Comment: and todays implementations can get fairly complicated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Microcontroller_Bus_Architecture there are links to other busses that are in use on that page

Comment: one computer or phone will have many/several busses, likely of different architectures depending on whose logic was purchased or designed and then glued together to make the chip or product